# How do I change the dataset when I Fine-Tuning the Whisper model?

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I tried to fine-tune the Whisper model by referring to the [article](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper). If want to refer to the code, please look at the [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sanchit-gandhi/notebooks/blob/main/fine_tune_whisper.ipynb).

All I want to do is change the common-voice dataset used in the article to my dataset.

I use a prepared common-voice dataset, it works very well. The common-voice dataset appears to use a pre-cached .arrow file. Therefore, it consumes very little memory.

[image: image.png]

Because of this, it is fast, and the whole process is handled well. But using my dataset does not work.(It consumes a lot of memory.)

Specifically, it takes a lot of time in the code below and does not work.

```
common_voice = common_voice.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=common_voice.column_names["train"], num_proc=2)
```

In my opinion, this is due to the raw data that was pre-cached. I import the dataset with the simple code below.

My code does not create an array cache file of voice files.

```
class DataLoader_AIHub:
    def __init__(self, rootPath):
        self.rootPath = rootPath

    def getData(self, max_files_to_load, startPoint=0):
        rootPath_audio = os.path.join(self.rootPath, 'audio')
        audioDirPaths = getDirList(rootPath_audio)

        total_files_loaded = 0

        data_list = []

        for audioDir in audioDirPaths:
            audioFileNames = getFileList(audioDir)
            audioFilePaths = [audioDir + '/' + str(item) for item in audioFileNames]
            labelFilePaths = [item.replace('/audio/','/label/').replace('.wav','.json') for item in audioFilePaths]
        
            for audioPath, labelPath in zip(audioFilePaths, labelFilePaths):
                jsonInfo = getJson(labelPath)

                if '(' in jsonInfo['발화정보']['stt']:
                    continue

                if startPoint > total_files_loaded:
                    total_files_loaded += 1
                    continue

                audio, sr = sf.read(audioPath)
                audioArray = audio.astype(np.float32)

                dict = {
                    'audio': {
                        'path': audioPath,
                        'array': audioArray,
                        'sampling_rate': sr
                    },
                    'sentence': re.sub('\r\n', '', jsonInfo['발화정보']['stt']),
                    'age': jsonInfo['녹음자정보']['age'],
                    'gender': jsonInfo['녹음자정보']['gender']
                }

                data_list.append(dict)

                total_files_loaded += 1

                if total_files_loaded >= max_files_to_load + startPoint: 
                    return Dataset.from_list(data_list)
                 
        return Dataset.from_list(data_list)
```

(It is a Korean dataset.)

Voice files (.wav) are sampled at 16 kHz, and audioArray refers to an array that has been decoded. The .arrow file is presumed to store these decoding arrays.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need. Instead of posting code fragments, please post a short but complete Python program which others can run. Then ask a very specific question about that program.

Comment: Are you sure you need all 10000 audio files in memory at the same time? Why do you need all of them? Why can't you process one or a few files at a time, keeping them memory requirements low?

Comment: @pts I'm sorry, my explanation was insufficient in asking questions. I've added a few more things. Thank you for reading.

Comment: 1. Check that your `data_list` doesn't contain too much data (e.g. the sampling rate and sample type are correct, and you are not accidentally importing audio files which are way too long). 2. Check how you can build a Dataset without keeping everything in memory. You have to start building it very early, and you have to stop building *data_list* (which keeps everything in memory).

Comment: Here is how you can write Apache Arrow table files without keeping all data in memory: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#writing-large-amounts-of-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are experiencing the same issue, please refer to the [link.](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/en/audio_load)

The solution is as follows.

```
from datasets import Audio

audio_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({
    "audio": ['audio_file_path_1.wav', 'audio_file_path_2.wav']}).cast_column("audio", Audio())
```

Then audio_dataset has the following format.

```
Dataset({
    features: ['audio'],
    num_rows: 2
})
```

Now you can use the code below here to check the contents.

```
audio_dataset['audio']
```

[image]

This `['audio']` contains dict `{'path', 'array', 'sampling_rate'}`
The important point here is that the array is generated 'on access', so it consumes very little memory.

You can now assign ten of thousands of voice files to Dataset variable and train them at once.

---

In addition, strictly speaking, it is inevitable to consume a lot of memory in the codelane below in the example above (due to feature extraction)

```
common_voice = common_voice.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=common_voice.column_names["train"], num_proc=2)
```

However, if use the code I suggested, Allocating a large amount of swap memory space in the operating system can improve the situation from a level where the program is unrunnable to a level where it can be executed without issues.